# Import & Export TeamCity build configuration template?

Tags: teamcity

In TeamCity you can setup a build configuration template, and create configurations according to that template. Is there a way to export this template to store it in a source control system for example, so that if you need to re-install TeamCity from scratch, you can just import the templates instead of having to re-create them manually?

Comment: You will be really surprised, but they cannot add this important feature for more than 4 years!!! You can watch request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-4124

Comment: This may be useful to you http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/01/teamcity-8-0-code-name-gaya-eap-is-open/ .

Answer (score 0):

If you run TeamCity on Windows and want to use Git to source control your configuration, you can use this Windows service I wrote which monitors the config folder for changes and commits them to git. The project is on GitHub: https://github.com/grenade/teamcity-config-monitor